# How can I pass in a query string variable to a link that has runat="server" tag on it

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
<a id="link1" href="home.aspx?theYear=<%=(selectYear)%>"></a>
```

vs.

```
<a runat="server" id="link2" href="home.aspx?theYear=<%=(selectYear)%>"></a>
```

In my code behind I have `public string selectYear="2017";` defined.

The first link I have works as expected. It will have the actual value of the selectYear as the query string variable. 
But the second one (the one with `runat="server"`) doesn't do that.

How can I have the `runat="server"` and still be able to make it behave like the first link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[<%= %>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5(VS.71).aspx) is a shortcut for `Response.Write` so it won't work inside your user control.

So can implement that using DataBinding markup `<%# %>`, but you have to be sure that someone will call the `DataBind` method- You could call the DataBind manually, `link2.DataBind()`, or call the page DataBind in case you have many links like that.

```
<a runat="server" id="link2" href="home.aspx?theYear=<%# selectYear%>"></a>
```

Another way to implement that is by just simple set the NavigateUrl from the server side:

```
link2.NavigateUrl = $"home.aspx?theYear={selectYear}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Well with runat="server", this anchor will be accessible in the code behind. So i will suggest you to write that in code behind as follows:

```
public string selectYear { get { return "2017"; } }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        link2.HRef = "home.aspx?theYear=" + selectYear;
    }
```

Comment: Can you mark that as correct if it's working as well